# Updating the value of an attribute on an instance of a class

Tags: python, class

I was not sure how to word this problem I'm having and after 4 hours of searching I am left here to ask. So i will lay out my problem and hope for the best!

I have completed every step of this program and have gotten it to run, but my brain can not wrap around how to solve this problem.

Here is the instructions:

Match Coins: Create a coin toss game with two players.

Each player starts with 20 coins. Rules:

each player tosses their own coin

If the coins match,

Player1 gets Player2’s coin.

If not, the Player2 gets the coin from Player1.

Whoever has the most coins wins.

In main(), create a while loop that asks to user to continue play.

In each loop, report the results … coins matched?

Total coins for each player?

The loop should toss the coins at least once.

A ‘Coin’ class is needed. The class requires:

The methods `__init__()`, `toss()`, `get_sideup()`, `get_amount()`, `set_amount()`

The class needs the attributes ’__amount’, initialized to 20, and ’__sideup’ 
initialized to one of two values, ‘Heads’ or ‘Tails’.

‘toss()’ method : generates a random value of ‘0’ or ‘1’, assigning ‘Heads’ or ‘Tails’ accordingly.

‘get_sideup()’ method : returns the current value of __sideup.

‘set_amount()’ method : passes a +1 or -1 to change __amount, depending on the results of the toss.

‘get_amount()’ method : returns the current value of __amount.

I have most of this working but I can not figure out how to add coins to one instance and subract from the next.
(I put self.get_amount as filler in the function im having problems with)

Here is my code:

```
import random


class Coin (object):
    def __init__ (self, __amount = 20, __sideup = "Heads"):

        self.__amount = __amount
        self.__sideup = __sideup

    def toss (self):
        val = random.randint(0,1)
        if val == 0:
            self.__sideup = "Heads"
        else:
            self.__sideup = "Tails"

    def get_sideup (self):
        return self.__sideup

    def get_amount(self,):
        return self.__amount

    def set_amount (self, __amount):
        self.get_amount





c1 = Coin()
c2 = Coin()
play = input ("Do you want to play? (Y/N): ")
while play == "Y" or "y":
    c1.toss()
    c2.toss()
    if c1.get_sideup() == c2.get_sideup():
        c1.set_amount(+1)
        c2.set_amount(-1)
        print("player 1 wins")
    else:
        c1.set_amount(-1)
        c2.set_amount(+1)
        print("player 2 wins")

    print(" player1: " + str(c1.get_amount()) + " and player2: " + str(c2.get_amount()))
    play = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ")
```

Thank you to anyone who reaches out. If the answer to my question is on here please link it. I'm a beginner and not sure how to word my questions very well.

Comment: What do you think your implementation of `set_amount` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update the self.__amount property of your coin object by rebinding it to the sum of __amount and self.__amount in your coin's set_amount method.

```
def set_amount (self, __amount):
    self.__amount = self.__amount + __amount
```

or a little more succinctly,

```
def set_amount (self, __amount):
    self.__amount += __amount
```

Comment: @AndJustice4All x By the way, there is also a bug in your program on this line: `while play == "Y" or "y":`

Comment: Yes I am working on this. Currently a student in a python program with a prof that dosn't know python..

Comment: Any tips would be great!